# Macbook5,2 -- Can't connect to WiFi (18.04.4)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu on my old Macbook, and I'm not able to connect to WiFi. Nearby networks do appear, but when I try to connect to any network, I receive the error message "Connection failed -- Activation of network connection failed."

`lspci` shows:

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)`

`iwconfig` shows:

```
wls4      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

ens5      no wireless extensions.
```

I followed the instructions here ([Installing Broadcam Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)) to uninstall and re-install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package without success.

I know this has been asked a lot, but after searching through previous questions/answers, I'm not sure what else to try.

Thank you!

EDIT:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` shows:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev03)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: ssb, wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: You didn't read the "instructions" you have a link to. `bcmwl-kernel-source` is a wrong driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not sure what you mean by `bcmwl-kernel-source` is a wrong driver. According to the table in the top answer, `bcmwl-kernel-source` is correct for 14e4:4328 rev 03. For what it's worth, I also tried installing `firmware-b43-installer` instead just to see if it would work, and with that driver my wireless card wasn't recognized at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your help! I added the info you requested.

Comment: All looks good to me.